# javascript submit 2 forms not working in chrome

Tags: javascript, forms, google-chrome

I have 2 forms to be submitted on one submit click, to download 2 files.

This is downloading 2 files in Firefox, but downloads only 1 file in chrome.

I have edited and inserted full code as per the request.

Full code:

```
                <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>EXPORT INVOICE </title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">

    <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
      function runscript()
      {
        document.f1.submit();
        document.f2.submit();
      }
    </script>
    </head>

    <body>

    <form name="f1" method="post" action="export-tst-with-header.php" target="_blank">

    <table width="810" height="140" border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" class="uniq" align="center">
      <tr class="uniq">
        <td width="363" valign="middle">
        <br>
        <span class="sty2">Enter to export From Invoice No.:</span>     <input type="text" size='10' maxlength='10' name="finv" onblur="showfrom(this.value);">
        &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <span class="sty2">To Invoice No:</span>&nbsp; <input type="text"  size='10' maxlength='10' name="tinv" onblur="showto(this.value);">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="uniq">
        <td width="363" valign="top"><div align="center"><br>
            <br>
            </form>

            <form name="f2" method="post" action="export-tst-with-header2.php" target="_blank">
            </form>

            <input type="button" value="Export" onClick="runscript();" />



    &nbsp;&nbsp;
    &nbsp;&nbsp;
          <a href='index.htm' target='_parent'><input name="close" type="button" value="Close !"></a>
        </div></td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <br>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: There is a validation issue with your HTML, you open the first form tag before the table tag but close it inside the table. You may want to address that.

Comment: @sridhir: please post complete html and javascript code

Comment: I have just posted a part of code where i have an issue.

Comment: @Turnerj       I have fixed the form tag within <td></td>, even after this there is no effect in chrome, it downloads only the second file from second-from

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: Here is a test I ran, where I cleaned up a lot of your issues in HTML and JS.  I found that this solution will, in fact, hit both URLs in Chrome.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>EXPORT INVOICE </title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">

<script type="text/javascript">
    function runscript() {
        document.forms.f1.submit();
        window.setTimeout(function() {
            document.forms.f2.submit();
        }, 500);
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <table width="810" height="140" border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" class="uniq" align="center">
        <tr class="uniq">
            <td width="363" valign="middle">
                <form name="f1" method="post" action="export-tst-with-header.php" target="_blank">
                    <br />
                    <span class="sty2">Enter to export From Invoice No.:</span>
                    <input type="text" size='10' maxlength='10' name="finv" onblur="showfrom(this.value);" />
                    &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <span class="sty2">To Invoice No:</span>&nbsp; 
                    <input type="text"  size='10' maxlength='10' name="tinv" onblur="showto(this.value);" />
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="uniq">
            <td width="363" valign="top">
                <div align="center">
                <br />
                <br />
                <form name="f2" method="post" action="export-tst-with-header2.php" target="_blank">
                </form>
                <input type="button" value="Export" onClick="runscript();" />
                &nbsp;&nbsp;
                &nbsp;&nbsp;
                <a href='index.htm' target='_parent'><input name="close" type="button" value="Close !"></a>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It is the same, there is no difference even after changing javascript.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @LyubenTodorov, thanks for the clarification on site rules, but this is, in fact, an attempt at an answer... even if it didn't fix his problem.  The fact is that the document.forms collection is universal in JS for all browsers, whereas accessing an element at the document level is not.

Comment: @StevenMoseley     I have copied your code and tried in chrome version Version 26.0.1410.64, it is same as before, only 1 file is downloading.

Comment: @sndhar - What I noticed when testing this is that Chrome is loading both URLs in the same browser tab.  It may be loading the second before the first file has a chance to save.  Maybe adding a window.setTimeout() will help solve that issue?

Comment: @StevenMoseley     Thank you so much, it is working fine now in chrome.

Comment: In above example, I'm having two form actions is same and one form is dynamically generated and another one is static one. Above solution not works to me

Comment: @sankar - I suggest you start a new question for your unique problem.  You could link this question in it, so whoever answers it sees this solution for reference.

Comment: This solution worked well for me. Chrome loads both URLs in the 2 browser tabs.